# react-native-navigation : How to hide header to all the screens

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am able to `hide header` in my `stackNavigator` like this:

```
const StackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  ScreenOne:{
  screen:ScreenOne,
  navigationOptions: {
    header: null
    }
  }
})
```

But if I have multiple screens, and want to apply `header:null` to all the screens, how can I set the `navigationOptions`? 
For example, I tried this but won't work.

```
const StackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    ScreenOne:ScreenOne,
    ScreenTwo:ScreenTwo,
    ScreenThree:ScreenThree,
    navigationOptions: {
        header: null
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const StackNavigator = createStackNavigator(
    {
        ScreenOne:ScreenOne,
        ScreenTwo:ScreenTwo,
        ScreenThree:ScreenThree,
    },
    {
        defaultNavigationOptions: {
            header: null
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it Like this:

```
const StackNavigator = createStackNavigator(
{
    ScreenOne:ScreenOne,
    ScreenTwo:ScreenTwo,
    ScreenThree:ScreenThree,
},
{
    headerMode:'none'
}
)
```